# jQuery events not listened anymore when pagination

Tags: jquery, pagination, bootstrap-table

I'm using pagination implemented in `bootstrap-table`, and I recently noticed that when use it, my custom jQuery script doesn't work anymore.

To be more precise, here is a snippet :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.form-modal-confirm-remove').click(function() {

    alert("Test");

  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-table/1.11.1/locale/bootstrap-table-fr-FR.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-table/1.11.1/bootstrap-table.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-table/1.11.1/bootstrap-table.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<table data-toggle="table" data-classes="table table-hover table-condensed table-no-bordered" data-pagination="true" data-page-size="2">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Actions</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        1
      </td>
      <td>
        Test
      </td>
      <td>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-circle form-modal-confirm-remove" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Supprimer">
          <i class="fa fa-trash"></i>
        </button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        2
      </td>
      <td>
        Test
      </td>
      <td>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-circle form-modal-confirm-remove" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Supprimer">
          <i class="fa fa-trash"></i>
        </button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        3
      </td>
      <td>
        Test
      </td>
      <td>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-circle form-modal-confirm-remove" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Supprimer">
          <i class="fa fa-trash"></i>
        </button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

You can see that on click on remove button, an alert show up. Then, when you move to second page, the alert doesn't pop anymore.

You can go back to page 1, alert still not appear.

Comment: Go read up on _event delegation_.

Comment: @CBroe Thanks for the advice

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please use **.on** instead of **.click** method.
**.on** method will work for dynamically added elements.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(document).on('click','.form-modal-confirm-remove',function() {

    alert("Test");

  });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

It because the DOM was loaded again, and we don't have event listener for it. You need to print the js handler together with your delete button for second page. or simply add.

What are you using in the backend? if PHP or similar then you can dynamically generate IDs. But in case if you are not, then simply you may..

```
<buttontype="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-circle form-modal-confirm-remove" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Supprimer" onclick="delete_row();"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></button>
```

---

```
function delete_row(this) {
    alert('hello');
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation !

Comment: give a thumbs up!!